# Where can I find users created in cosmo DB?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have created users from c# using the example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data

When I want to see the list of users can not find it in the portal, where can I find it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways.

You can either send get request as shown below to get list of all users in the instance.
([From Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-users))

> **GET https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/users**
>
> The {databaseaccount} is the name of the Azure Cosmos DB account
>   created under your subscription. The {db-id} value is the user
>   generated name/ID of the database, not the system generated ID (rid).

OR you can go to portal and open your CosmosDB resource and go to "Access Control (IAM)".
Then Click on "Role Assignment" to view list of users.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi
I created a user in c# but it is not visible in IAM. I know the user has been created, because I can't create a new one with the same name.
Any ideas?